# Does the complexity of summing booleans differ from summing integers?

Tags: integer, boolean, double, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I am summing a fixed number `k` boolean values: `A = a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_k`. (or equivalently counting logical ones)

Does this have the same computational complexity as summing `k` arbitrary 8, 16, 32, 64 bit integers or doubles: `B = b_1 + b_2 + ... + b_k`?

If yes, please explain why.

If no, what is the appropriate complexity of sum `A`?

Comment: How do you define "summing booleans"?

Comment: @amit as counting the number of bits that are in the `true` state i.e. counting logical ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're adding up *k* boolean (0/1) values, you're essentially just counting up how many 1's there are. This can be done in time O(k) by just scanning over the numbers and counting upward for each 1 you read.

Now, imagine that you're adding up *k* b-bit values. This will require *k* additions, but each addition will take time proportional to the number of digits in the numbers that you're summing up. Imagine you're adding the total T to some number in the list x. Since x is b bits long, you'll spend O(b) work adding those bits into the total T. You may then need to do a ripple carry across some of the bits of T. Since each bit represents the next power of two, it becomes progressively less and less likely that you'll flip those higher bits, so overall the work done works out to O(kb). Notice that this is asymptotically slower than O(k) for large b.

Now, most machines can perform arithmetic on words of some fixed size w in time O(1). Therefore, if you do the arithmetic on an actual machine, the true runtime will be O(kb / w), so if you pick a number of bits that matches the computer's word size, this is asymptotically no better than counting the number of 1's in the boolean case. However, if you're dealing with arbitrary-precision numbers, summing booleans is definitely more efficient.

Comment: I refuse to read a post of yours that does not end with "Hope it helps!"

Comment: @amit I got skewered on Meta for doing that and was told by a moderator to stop because it violates SO policies, so I've had to stop doing that, unfortunately. :-(

Comment: that's a shame. I liked it :(

Comment: @templatetypedef But doesn't O(bk) = O(k) for fixed b, ergo they're asymptotically equivalent?

Comment: @Jim For a fixed b, yes, they're the same asymptotically. However, it's not unusual to take the integer size into account when calculating the runtime, since you might want to know how the algorithm performs on integers of arbitrary size.